# Include a Partial view conditionally based on debug or production in ASP.Net MVC site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view that includes only basic HTML, no razor code or model.
I use this to set up some "guides" for page layout.

What would be the proper/simplest way to only include this partial when the site is run in debug mode?

I know that in  my compiled code I could use directives in my C# code to include sections. Is there something similar in razor?

Comment: I would suggest to use [configuration transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Simply add an appsetting value in your web.config.

Comment: You could define a View variable and set it to true based off of `#if DEBUG` in your compiled code, and then set the value based upon that variable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` which would check `web.config`s' debug setting:

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) {
    //Do something here.
}
```

**OR** use an extension helper method:

```
public static Boolean DEBUG(this System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage page) {
// use this sequence of returns to make the snippet ReSharper friendly. 
#if DEBUG
        return true;
#else
        return false;
#endif
}
```

and usage:

```
@if(DEBUG()) {
    //debug code here
} else {
    //release code here
}
```

Comment: for the extension method, I think it would be better to just return true in the `#if DEBUG`, and return false right afterward.  There doesn't seem to be a need to assign a variable to this.

Comment: u'r right. thanks. I was just writing something to work. update answer with a code snippet that is friendly with resharper too :D

Comment: The first solution fits my needs perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My quick answer (this is what might do):

Create a web.config section like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="InProduction" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Then, check:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 =
    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
if (rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
{
    bool inProd = rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings["InProduction"];
}
```

Then set a viewbag variable based on the `bool` and show in your Razor view:

```
ViewBag.ShowPartial = inProd;
```

Razor:

```
@if (ViewBag.ShowPartial)
{
    @Html.Partial("MyProductionPartial")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a static property in a class:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static bool IsDebugMode {get; set;}
}
```

... and then in your Global.asax.cs file, on start up, you could do something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    Foo.IsDebugMode = true;
#endif
```

... then in your views you could look for `Foo.IsDebugMode` (you might need to add a reference).

Or... if you have overridden your ViewPage class, you can add it as a property right there... it'll look like it belongs.  :)